# С++ функция для сортировки массива

Tags: c++, сортировка, указатели

Я недавно начал изучать С++, поставил перед собой задачу написать программу, которая будет сортировать массив (не важно каким методом), таким принципом, что функция сортировки должна быть написана отдельно и вызываться в главной функции, прошу закомментировать моменты работы с указателями (у меня с ними не ладится).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib>;
int area[1000];
..............
int sorting(void *a, void *b)
{
  int result;
  unsigned long 
    *pa = (unsigned long*)a,
    *pb = (unsigned long*)b;
  if((int*)*pa > (int*)*pb) result = 1;
  if((int*)*pa < (int*)*pb) result = -1;
  if((int*)*pa == (int*)*pb) result = 0;
  return result;
}
int main()
{
  qsort((void*)area, 1000, sizeof(int), sorting);
  ......
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Простите, но отсюда я практически ничего не понял.

Comment: Слишком много излишеств. Можно написать короче и проще.

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Прочитайте в хелпе про qsort(...). Разберите пример, который там приводится, и освежите свои знания относительно указателей на функции.
int sortng(void* a, void*b) - это ф-ция, которая "обучает" qsort(...) различать БОЛЬШЕ, РАВНО и МЕНЬШЕ для избранного типа элементов массива. Ее адрес должен быть последним фактическим параметром у qsort(...)

Comment: Спасибо, я разобрался сам.

Answer (score 3):

> Слишком много излишеств. Можно написать короче и проще.

Например, так:

```
#include<stdlib.h>;
int sorter(void *a, void *b)
{
    return *(int*)a-*(int*)b;
}
int main()
{
    int array[]={...заполняем массив...};
    qsort(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(int), sizeof(int), sorter);
    return 0;
}
```

Или так:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int array[]={...заполняем массив...};
    std::sort(array, array+sizeof(array)/sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

Оба варианта используют стандартные функции.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле указатели - не такая сложная вещь, как кажется. Указатель - это переменная, которая содержит адрес в памяти другой переменной. Чтобы получить адрес какой-то переменной, делают так: `&a`. Чтобы получить с помощью указателя доступ к переменной, на которую он указывают, применяют оператор разыменования *.  В выражении `*a + *b` будет складываться не сами указатели, а те переменные, на которые они указывают.

При любой сортировке основными операциями являются сравнение двух переменных и обмен значениями между ними. С помощью указателей это делается так

сравнение

```
if (*a < *b ) {.....}
```

обмен значениями (для int)

```
int temp;
temp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = temp;
```

Это кирпичики, из которых можно построить желаемую Вами функцию. Успехов.